# Best approach to 2D racing game AI?

Tags: 2d, ai, racing

I have no experience in AI **at all**, but I would like to know how I could do this?
Even if the AI just followed a path how could I do this?

Comment: How could you do what, precisely?

Comment: It depends on a lot of other factors - e.g. if there's no car-car collision you can just hard-code car movements or use 'ghosts' from replays of previous races.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought naive approach would be to create a list of points  corresponding to the coordinates of the track curves (probably more points would be needed to prevent the AI keep going against walls after an unplanned collision with another car). When the AI car is close enough to the next point, you would put it (the point)  in the end of the list. All the AI car would need to do is to always go in a straight line in the direction of the next point in the list.

Comment: Yeah, basically waypoints. You have the car use basic [steering behaviors](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/) to go from one waypoint to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make a type of path that the car follows. First, you need to make the car just drive. (Make the car drive forward forever). Create a rectangle at each turn on the track then make if statements for when the AI car intersects them. When the AI intersects them(the rectangles) make it rotate according to where it needs to turn.